# Virtual Machine Status

Tags: azure

When I shutdown a VM via RDP the VM status is showing as Stopped in the VM Overview page.

But the status is being shown as Running on the Virtual Machines page.

So, my doubt will I be charged if the machine is in Running State on the Virtual Machine page? Is it a normal behavior?

Thanks,
Sai Ganesh.

Comment: You should ask Microsoft about Azure billing questions.  However, in Azure a VM is typically charged until it is deallocated.  Merely shutting down is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you shutdown the VM from inside Windows you will still be charged. To not be charged the VM needs to show as "deallocated" which requires you to turn it off from the portl/CLI/PowerShell.